# Python does not recognize subclass unless it's imported in __init__.py

Tags: python, oop, python-import

I have a project with multiple sub-folders, most of which are Python packages. One of them contains an abstract class called BaseStep (created using the `abc` module), which during runtime looks for subclasses of itself using: `for subclass in cls.__subclasses__(): ...`. `BaseStep` is located in the `pipeline` directory, in a python file named `base_step.py`, and is thus accessed by doing `pipeline.base_step.BaseStep`.

This package looks like:

```
pipeline/
    __init__.py
    base_step.py
```

In another Python package, I would like to create some examples of how to use BaseStep. This package is called `examples` and I have a python file there called `sample_step.py`. Within `sample_step.py` I have created a class that extends the `BaseStep` class called `SampleStep`. Thus it is accessed by doing `examples.sample_step.SampleStep`.

This package looks like:

```
examples/
    __init__.py
    sample_step.py
```

When I try to access the `__subclasses__()` during runtime, however, I cannot see `SampleStep` listed as one of them.

The only way `SampleStep` shows up as a subclass of `BaseStep` is if the `__init__.py` of the `pipeline` directory includes an import of the `SampleStep`:

```
from examples.sample_step import SampleStep
```

Why is this the case? Why do I have to import my sample step inside the *pipeline* package? Why can't `BaseStep` identify subclasses in other packages? Any help understanding inheritance and importing would be deeply appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments. From the comments, I realized I did not explain how SampleStep is being imported, and deleted some of my responses to the comments.

The `examples` module actually looks like this:

```
examples/
    __init__.py
    runner.py
    sample_step.py
```

Within **init**.py, I have `from examples.sample_step import SampleStep`. Then I call `runner.py`, which instantiates `SampleStep` by calling a function in `BaseStep` that looks at its subclasses. At least that is what it tries to do -- it fails because `BaseStep` does not realize that `SampleStep` is a subclass.

@Blckknght said "You can import the module from anywhere (as long as that "anywhere" is getting loaded itself)". So the more specific question is: why doesn't importing `SampleStep` within the `examples/__init__.py` at runtime get `BaseStep` to recognize that it's a subclass?

Comment: And where is the code that calls the part of `BaseStep` that does `for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():` located?

Comment: The code that calls BaseStep for the subclasses is located in the same package, in `pipeline`.

Answer (score 3):

Python is a dynamic language. Things like class definitions technically happen at runtime, not some earlier compile time as in other languages like C and Java. This means that until you import your `sample_step` module and run definition of its `SampleStep` class, that class doesn't exist as far as the Python interpreter is concerned.

You can import the module from anywhere (as long as that "anywhere" is getting loaded itself). It just needs to be loaded once for the subclass to show up in the `BaseStep.__subclasses__` list.

Answer (score 2):

The `SampleStep` subclass **does not exist** until its file is imported.